# How to implement QR code scanning?

Tags: solidity

In some DApps, when they want to connect a wallet, you can click on 'Connect to Wallet' and it opens a QR code for App to scan and authorize it. How do we implement this functionality? is there a design pattern?

For Example: https://dex.onxrp.com/
When we click on 'Connect to wallet', you can scan the QR code through XUMM wallet and authorize your wallet.

Comment: You might want to check: [WalletConnect](https://walletconnect.com/), this is how I implemented this functionality. It is supported by all major wallets.

Answer (score 0):

The QR code contains the [DeepLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_deep_linking) (URL). A mobile app can register itself in Mobile OS as a handler for specific protocols, like `mysuperapp://...`, when opening the link, the OS starts the app and passes the link to the app. The app gets all the required information, tokens, or secrets from the link.

- In SingleVendor communication - there is no standard in parameters, *`onxrp` uses their own wallet app*.
- In Vendor-to-Vendor communication - similar to API, there should be documentation which links and parameters the installed application can handle

Comment: I just want a high level flow of implementation, what deeplink url to generate from my dapp

Comment: It depends on what mobile app you want to communicate with and what you want to achieve. Look into their documentation.